# how to pass JVM arguments in AWS ECS?

Tags: jvm-arguments, aws-ecs

I am trying to set up a microservice in Amazon ECS. How can JVM arguments be configured and passed to the microservice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We do this sort of thing by passing them as `env` variables on the task. When you edit your container in your task, scroll down to the `Env Variables` section:

[image]

You can then reference these as normal `env` variables on the command line when you launch your application.

Comment: ECS lauches the docker container and the application automatically. so, at what level shoudl these parameters be referred or how these variables can be referred through command line?

Answer (score 0):

You can set an ENTRYPOINT in your Dockerfile like:
ENTRYPOINT ["java","-Xms1024m","-Xmx1800m","-jar","/app.jar"]