# Adding Jenkins system property doesn't survive a restart

Tags: jenkins

Trying to add new system properties to Jenkins through its GUI through script console like :
System.setProperty("hudson.model.DirectoryBrowserSupport.CSP", "")
and some other properties but they're removed whenever I restart Jenkins.

Is there a way to save the properties and survive the restart of Jenkins or is there any other way other than script console to add those properties?

PS: I'm running Jenkins on AWS ECS container and I don't have /etc/sysconfig/jenkins or /etc/default/jenkins path to add the setting to the java args.

Answer (score 2):

To set system properties permanently in a [official Jenkins docker image](https://hub.docker.com/r/jenkins/jenkins/), you need to pass it as JVM arguments to the container through the variable environment `JAVA_OPTS`.
For example :

```
docker run --name=docker-jenkins --env JAVA_OPTS="-Dhudson.model.DirectoryBrowserSupport.CSP=\"\""
```

So, on AWS ECS, you need to find a way to pass environment variable to the container. Maybe, [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49512115/how-to-pass-jvm-arguments-in-aws-ecs) can help you.